# Pushout homotopy squares in motivic homotopy theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, motivic-homotopy

I am using Vladimir Voevodsky's [notes](https://www.math.ias.edu/vladimir/sites/math.ias.edu.vladimir/files/Nordfjordeid_lectures_published.pdf) on motivic homotopy theory and I am having trouble understanding the proofs of Corollary 2.20 and Lemma 2.21. Both of these deal with homotopy pushout squares and I suspect that I am misinterpreting what Lemma 2.19 (which is cited in the proofs) is saying.

From what I understand, Lemma 2.19 says that if

[image]

is an upper distinguished square of schemes (see Definition 2.18), then the diagram

[image]

(now viewed in the category of spaces) is a pushout diagram. Is my interpretation of this result correct? The proof of this result is supposed to follow from the fact that spaces are sheaves in the Nisnevich topology. Since I am not too familiar with this topology, I did not try to prove this statement myself, which might have resulted in me interpreting the result incorrectly.

If my interpretation is indeed correct, how does Lemma 2.19 imply Corollary 2.20 (a)? How does the smash product show up here?

Finally, what is the proof argument for Lemma 2.21 (a)? I understand why the given sequence is an exact triangle. It seems like they are using $S^1_s\wedge S^1_t\cong \text{Cone}(\sum^\infty_{s,t}(\mathbb{A}^1-0)\longrightarrow \sum^\infty_{s,t}\mathbb{A}^1)$, but I don't see how to prove that.

Answer (score 2):

For Corollary 2.20 (a):

Apply Lemma 2.16 to the monomorphism $$W_+\to U_+\vee V_+$$ so we get the traingle
$$\Sigma^{\infty}W_+\to \Sigma^{\infty}(U_+\vee V_+)\to \Sigma^{\infty}(\dfrac{U_+\vee V_+}{W_+}).$$

Now it suffices to conclude that $$\Sigma^{\infty}(U_+\vee V_+)\simeq \Sigma^{\infty}(U_+)\vee \Sigma^{\infty}(V_+)$$ and $$\Sigma^{\infty}(\dfrac{U_+\vee V_+}{W_+})\simeq \Sigma^{\infty}(X_+). $$
The first one is easy to see and the second one follows from Lemma 2.19 (equivalence at the level of spaces before the infinite suspension.)

For the 2nd part of the question: for the proof of 2.21(a):

By the distinguished triangle we have an equivalence
$$\Sigma^{\infty}(\mathbb{A}^1/\mathbb{A}^1-0)\to \Sigma^{\infty}(\mathbb{A}^1-0)[1]).$$ Now simply observe that $$\mathbb{A}^1-0)[1]\simeq S^1_s\wedge S^1_t.$$